# Cross-platform non-ASCII symbols in filenames with TrueCrypt

Tags: windows-7, unicode, truecrypt, filename

I have a TrueCrypt volume created under Windows 7. Some folders and file names contain Cyrillic symbols. When mounting the volume in Ubuntu 10.10, I see question marks instead of those letters. Is there a solution, or should I avoid non-ASCII symbols if I want to open the volume in Windows and Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. Here's how I resolved it.

The truecrypt volume you created was most likely formatted as FAT32. When mounting FAT in Linux default charset is iso8859-1, although long filenames in Windows are stored on disk in Unicode format.

Solution: specify `iocharset=utf8` in Truecrypt for **Mount options** (globally in preferences or for specific volume in advanced options).

Comment: Thank you! I apologize for slow response, I don't have Linux at hand to check this. I'll approve the answer as soon as I test it on my system.

Comment: If you're mounting the truecrypt volume in the command line, the proper way of passing Yaroslav's option is with `--fs-options=iocharset=utf8`